# Scroll to elements from two different lists in the same document that have the same id value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

In the following case there are two lists, one being nested within the other.

```html
<q-list>
    <q-item
        v-for="item in data"
        :key="item.id_data"
        :id="item.id_data"
        >
        <q-item-section>
            <div>
                <span {{ item.name }} </span>

                <q-item
                    v-for="stuff in item"
                    :key="stuff.id_stuff"
                    :id="stuff.id_stuff">
                    <q-item-section>
                        <span"> {{ stuff.name }} </span>
                    </q-item-section>
                </q-item>

            </div>
        </q-item-section>
    </q-item>
</q-list>
```

Two click events can be triggered that generated a scroll to a element of the lists:

1- In the first case, the scroll must be done for the element to which the **id** corresponds to **item.id_data**

2- In the second case, the scroll must be done for the element to which the **id** corresponds to **stuff.id_stuff**

This means that the data id value can match the stuff id value (i.e., item.id_data = **4**, stuff.id_stuff = **4**).

This causes problems when using document.getElementById(id).

Example of the scrollTo function:

```
scrollTo (id) {
    const ele = document.getElementById(id)
    const target = getScrollTarget(ele)
    const offset = ele.offsetTop - ele.scrollHeight    
    const duration = 500
    setScrollPosition(target, offset, duration)
},
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind a prefix to each ID to differentiate them:

```html
<q-list>
    <q-item
        v-for="item in data"
        :key="item.id_data"
               
        :id="'data_' + item.id_data"
        >
        <q-item-section>
            <div>
                <span {{ item.name }} </span>

                <q-item
                    v-for="stuff in item"
                    :key="stuff.id_stuff"
                            
                    :id="'stuff_' + stuff.id_stuff">
                    <q-item-section>
                        <span"> {{ stuff.name }} </span>
                    </q-item-section>
                </q-item>

            </div>
        </q-item-section>
    </q-item>
</q-list>
```